# How to hide ActionBar in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Is there a possible way to hide ActionBar?

[image]

Comment: That thing is called **`ActionBar`**. Please search with this keyword to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear and you should consider editing it, although,
I guess what you need is to change the `theme` of your `activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, i.e.:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to hide action bar from all activities of the project.. then change the `theme` of your application in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**1.**
Add it in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

and use the style at AndroidManifest.xml.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

**2.** Or Simple Solution.. just replace theme attribute with this line..

```
<application
    .
    .
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
    . >
```

If you Want to hide actionBar for particular activity... then

**1.**  Change `Theme` of the activity..

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
```

**2.** Programmatically Hide the actionBar..

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); or getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to hide Action Bar in one activity only, put this in onCreate():

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); or getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting activity theme in Manifest,

```
 <activity 
        android:name=".AnActivity"
        android:label="@string/a_string"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen>
    </activity>
```